# MySQL: Getting relevant result for each selected row

Tags: php, mysql, performance

i am using the basic select query below to show the latest 20 rows from my table.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table  ORDER BY id DESC limit 0,20
```

Then i want to get relevant result for each of rows selected above... what i'm currently doing is run following query in 'php' for each row in a loop..

```
SELECT * MATCH (title)
AGAINST('$main_title'IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)AS 
score FROM my_table  MATCH(title)  AGAINST('$main_title'IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
HAVING score > 10  ORDER BY score DESC
```

so the complete 'PHP' code looks like this:

```
<?php
// First Query 
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table  ORDER BY id DESC limit 0,20");  
$result = mysql_query($query) 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "Main Topic: ".$row['title'];
$main_title = $row['title'];
    echo "Related to this Topic:";

   // Second Query 
    $related_query= mysql_query("
    SELECT * MATCH (title)
    AGAINST('$main_title'IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)AS 
    score FROM my_table  MATCH(title)  AGAINST('$main_title'IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
    HAVING score > 10  ORDER BY score DESC
    ");  
    $related_result = mysql_query($related_query) 

            while($related_row = mysql_fetch_array($related_result)){
            echo  "<br>". $related_row['title'];
    }


}
?>
```

**but i know that running a second query within a loop in very inefficient, so i want to get these "related results" also in the main query (or in a separate single query without having to run it within a loop)**

Basically i'm looking for a method to do the same, more efficiently..

is there a way i can do this?

thank you

Comment: define "relevant result" so that we would not have to guess :)

Comment: relevant result is a full text search against "title" column" in each selected row...

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you only want to have the title and the score, would this work?

```
SELECT MATCH(title) AGAINST('$main_title' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) as SCORE,
title FROM my_table WHERE  
MATCH(title) AGAINST('$main_title' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
AND score > 10 AND id<=20 ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Comment: i know how to search for relevant results. the problem is i have to run that second query for each row in first query (within a loop in php). i just want to avoid running that second query again and again in a loop.. i hope im clear enough

Comment: this query runs against the whole table. I have added the row clause to limit it by row like you did.

Comment: but i want to get these "related result" for each row separately.. i mean for row1 a separate set of "related rows" and for row 2 another set of "related rows".. like that...

Comment: sorry i think i wasn't clear enough.. now i edited the question so it should be clearer...

Answer (score 1):

First, I think the second query is more like this:

```
SELECT mt.*,
       MATCH (title) AGAINST('$main_title'IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score
FROM my_table mt
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('$main_title' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) > 10
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

If you want to do this only for 20 ids in `my_table`, then use a subquery:

```
SELECT mt.*,
       MATCH (title) AGAINST('$main_title'IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score
FROM (select mt.*
      from my_table mt
      order by id desc
      limit 0, 20
     ) mt
WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('$main_title' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) > 10
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Comment: Gordon Linoffthanks. but i can't understand how i can echo out the 20 main titles. sorry i'm bit new in to this..

Comment: @user3327581 . . . The second query should be doing in a single query what your queries are doing in a loop.  It should be returning the same results.

Comment: but how can a get a list of main topics with this query? sorry if i wan't clear enough.. i've edited the question so now it should be clearer...